# Dnn Module is not appearing in view mode

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am facing an issue when added a new page in DNN 08.02.00.

The issue is - Used module is not appearing on the page on view mode but when I click on edit page button my module is appearing. basically module is appearing on edit mode and not appearing in view mode.

These are following steps for creating a new page with existing Module:-

1. I am login with super admin user.
2. Click on Pages-> Add New Page
3. Create a page with the permission of the administrator
4. Add New Module on Page.
5. Close edit button

and right now I am not able to see this module without edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permission issue.  Does the module inherit permissions from the page?

Another place to look is at the container.  V

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

after create a new page, we have to publish it.

In my case i am not able to publish my page just because of my dnn licence is expire. after renewing it, I am able to publish it .